# Issue with @Before and POST request

Tags: actframework

I'm trying to implement simple security using Interception following the example in the documentation:

```
    @Before(except= {"register", "login"})
    public void checkAuthentication(H.Session session) {
        if (null != session && session.get("username") == null) {
            redirect("login");
        }
    }

    @GetAction("/login")
    public Result login() {
        return render("login");
    }

    @PostAction("/login")
    public void doLogin(String username, String password, H.Session session) {
        // do some login stuff + register session variables
    }
```

The interceptor works fine (it redirects me to the login form when trying to open any other page than the ones listed). However, it doesn't work on POST, e.g. when I try to submit the login form, doLogin() is never called and I'm sent back to the login screen (same behaviour for the registration form).

Changing the syntax to include only pages to intercept, the login works as expected:

```
    @Before(only = "home")
```

However this is a bit inconvenient, given that I have about four pages that don't need interception and a lot more that do.

Does this method not work with POST requests or am I doing something entirely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add `"doLogin"` into your `@Before` annotation:

```
@Before(except= {"register", "login", "doLogin"})
public void checkAuthentication(H.Session session) {
    if (null != session && session.get("username") == null) {
        redirect("login");
    }
}
```